# Is it possible to create a Script in Blender which can perform Rendering?

Tags: python, scripting

I want to render different combinations of colors on a 3D mesh, but i figured that rendering them one by one would be time consuming.

Is it possible to create a python script in blender which allocates the color to the 3D object, renders it as an image and also save the image?

Comment: Yes, it is. https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5brendering%5d%20%5bpython%5d%20object